# Force prompt on specific directories

Tags: bash, unix, prompt

Is there a way to change the prompt on a different directories on the same machine? For example, I want a simple prompt "[\W] \$" in development directories.

Ideas?

Comment: It depends on which shell you're using.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can put something like this in your `.bashrc`.

```
prompt-function() {
    case $PWD in
        /a/dev/dir\
        |/another/dev/dir) 
            PS1="[\W] \$"
            ;;
        *)
            # Change this to the default prompt
            PS1="\$ "
            ;;
     esac
}

PROMPT_COMMAND=prompt-function
```

Comment: +1 I would use a `case` statement instead of a series of `elsif` statements. You could even put the directories in an array and iterate over them with a for loop. You could use globbing patterns with any of those techniques or you could use regexes with `[[ $PWD =~ $pattern ]]`.

Comment: @Dennis: I edited my answer with a `case` statement. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: If the action is the same, you can list the action once after alternative cases separated by pipe characters. `foo|bar) action;;` You can put the cases on separate lines by putting a backslash and newline before or after the pipe character.

Comment: @Dennis: Edited my answer accordingly, again. Thanks for the suggestion!